# Pasta .ssh não é criada ao gerar o comando ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "seu_email@provedor.com"

Tags: git, ssh

Ao tentar criar uma chave *ssh* a Pasta *.ssh* não é criada no windows ao gerar o comando `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "seu_email@provedor.com"`. Com isso não consigo a chave que deveria ficar dentro dessa pasta.

Comment: Possível duplicata de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/273662/64969?

Answer (score -1):

Conseguir gerar a chave .ssh no windows. Apos criar manualmente a pasta SSH no diretório /GNU (essa pasta é criada apos a instalação padrão no windows)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Apos isso executei o comando:

> ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "seu_email@provedor.com"

gerando perfeitamente a chave ssh:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei explicar porque no windows existe este bug, não aconteceu comigo no linux. Em todo caso, problema resolvido.

Comment: Já respondeu isso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/273662/5878), então não precisa replicar a resposta, basta marcar como duplicata.