# Erro ao criar pasta .ssh no windows

Tags: git, ssh

Quando executo o comando `$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "meu.nome.silva@QQQ.com.br"` recebo a mensagem de erro:

> Generating public/private rsa key pair. Enter file in which to save
>   the key (/c/Program Files (x86)/GNU/SSH/.ssh/id_rsa)         : Could
>   not create directory '/c/Program Files (x86)/GNU/SSH/.ssh': No such
>   file o         r directory Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
>   Enter same passphrase again: Saving key "/c/Program Files
>   (x86)/GNU/SSH/.ssh/id_rsa" failed: No such file or          directory

Tentei executar com administrador e recebo a mesma mensagem

Comment: Utilize `sudo ssh-keygen ...`

Comment: Mas e os paramentos como o endereço de email ?

Comment: seria em um segundo passo ?

Comment: estou recendo a mensagem: Could not create directory '/c/Program Files (x86)/GNU/SSH/.ssh': No such file or directory

Comment: Tenho de criar essa pasta ?

Comment: lembrando que estou usando o windows modo adminstrador

Comment: Engraçado... qual o valor de `$HOME`? Essa pasta `.ssh` deveria estar na `$HOME` do usuário, não nos arquivos de programa

Comment: C:\Users\alex.jose.silva\.ssh não tem nada!

Comment: usei a instalação padrão!

Comment: Essa questão não trata de versionamento de artefato nem de comunicação/uso do GitHub. Não tem porque ter tais tags

Comment: Nem faz sentido ter git, ele sendo analisada individualmente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conseguir gerar a chave .ssh no windows. Apos criar manualmente a pasta SSH no diretório /GNU (essa pasta é criada apos a instalação padrão no windows)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Apos isso executei o comando:

> ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "seu_email@provedor.com"

gerando perfeitamente a chave ssh:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei explicar porque no windows existe este bug, não aconteceu comigo no linux. Em todo caso, problema resolvido.